# Routing to component not working

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularJs 1.5 to build a web application, new to this technology and still learning the ropes, so far my folder structure looks like this

[image]

As of now, there are two buttons on the screen, viz. "dashboard" and "about" buttons. The about buttons works fine as uses an inline template, however the dashboard button stops when I give it a component to render.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="dashboard">

<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
</head>

<body>

    <a ui-sref="dashboard" ui-sref-active="active">dashboard</a>
    <a ui-sref="about" ui-sref-active="active">About</a>
    <!-- The <ui-view> tag is a UI-Router viewport. When a state is activated, the state’s view will be loaded into the viewport. -->
    <ui-view></ui-view>



    <!-- Load scripts here-->
    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/components/dashboardPage/dashboardPage.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module("dashboard", ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.config(function($stateProvider) {
    var states = [{
        name: 'dashboard',
        url: '/dashboard',
        component: 'dashboardPage'
    }, {
        name: 'about',
        url: '/about',
        template: '<h3>Its the UI-Router hello world app!</h3>'
    }];

    // Loop over the state definitions and register them
    states.forEach(function(state) {
        $stateProvider.state(state);
    });
});
```

**dashboardPage.js**

```
angular.module("dashboard")
.component("dashboardPage", {
    template: '<h3>Dashboard page</h3>',
    // templateUrl: 'dashboardPage.html',
    bindings: {},
    controller: function($element){

    }
});
```

On click of "dashboard" button, I was expecting it show `<h3>Dashboard page</h3>` but its not working.

What am I doing wrong here ? How to get routing working for components?

**Update:**
Made a [sample plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YyD7TdFVkJ6gyMKVKRhn?p=preview) and it works, however mine is still not working. 
I am now totally confused, where could I have gone wrong ?!

Comment: By not working I meant that it is showing a blank screen with just the two buttons and not throwing any error

Comment: What does the console say - Any errors ? And what are differences between the plnkr and the actual code.

Comment: Try updating the plnkr with exact libraries and version that you have.

Comment: @bhantol while making the plnkr, I identified that it was not working because the version I had in local which I installed through bower was v0.3 and their latest version is at v1. Going through their docs at https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/ , I found that they have stopped updating the bower repository.